# My react app not loading images and some components on older Safari Browsers. Shows SSL error

Tags: ios, node.js, reactjs, safari

Im using nodejs to host some images that my website uses. It works perfectly on newer versions of safari, chrome, and firefox. But for some people using old versions of safari, people with old ios devices, cannot use the website, because the images will not load due to an ssl error.

This is what appears in the console with older versions of safari.

Failed to load resource: An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made.

this is the website: https://nindoa.mx
My nodejs server uses https and has an AWS certificate using cloudfront.

Answer (score 0):

The error most probably is occurring `due to mismatch in TLS versions` supported by the device & Cloudfront.

Older devices works on TLS v1.1 or later, while the latest one on TLS v1.2 or newer.

Make sure while creating the Cloudfront cdn you have selected the correct configuration required. You need to identify the TLS supported by the model to debug the issue deeply.

> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/secure-connections-supported-viewer-protocols-ciphers.html